# What are the default values for docker-compose properties?

Tags: docker-compose

I'm looking for default values for properties listed on [the docker-compose reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)

e.g. what is the default build value ?

If all we have is the source code then that suffices I suppose, unless we have to dig for each setting individually rather than defaults being declared in a cohesive location.